# ConEmu: light colors like 91?

Tags: conemu

According to [this page](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#reset), the escape sequence `\e[91m` should produce a light red color, but it doesn't appear to have any effect in ConEmu. Is there a way to support these extended 'light' colors (without using `\e[1;31m` instead)?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to use uncommon to ANSI X3.64 code. ([prooflink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes))
2. What application you are trying to use? Bash? All known ports (cygwin/msys) [do not send ANSI to the RealConsole](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/CygwinAnsi) at all.

Comment: ConEmu build 141001: 'ESC [ 90..97 m' high intensity foreground color, 'ESC [ 100..107' high intensity background color.